# How to remove a rule from audtictl

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat, opensuse, audit-logging

There is a current rule in effect:

```
# auditctl -l
-a always,exclude -F msgtype>0
```

I am trying to remove it with:
`-d always,exclude -F msgtype>0`

but receive the error:
`-F missing operation for msgtype`

What is the proper way to remove this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you literally type `-F msgtype>0`? Then you probably have an empty file `0` in the current directory.

You need to escape the `>` character, perhaps like this:

```
-F 'msgtype>0'
```